# Use Http post to update data on server using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http, post

Currently have this

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("POST", 'url', true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                alert("xmlHttp.responseText: " + xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.send("json_name=" + JSON.stringify({ FirstName: "BOB" }));
```

however, I was wondering as to why the xmlHttp.status never changes from 0 to 200.

UPDATE: 
By 'url' I meant the location of the file. In my actual code I put the actual location of the file, its just that it had the IP address in it so I did not post that.
The URL I put is the correct one because above the POST function I have another function that uses GET, and it uses the same URL, and it works just fine.
So I was wondering if there are any other suggestions?

Comment: Check the 2nd argument of the `open` method : you passed a string containing the word "url".

Comment: you should pass respected site url to post the data

Answer (score 0):

In line 2: `xmlHttp.open("POST", "url", true);`, the second parameter you have is `"url"`.

This parameter is supposed to be the resource or file that you want to POST to the server. It is likely that "url" is not a resource or file on your computer (or at least in the working directory of the Javascript program).

Therefore, when you try to POST `"url"` it will not be a successful status of 200 because `"url"` does not exist.